# Apache unable to start

Tags: apache, iis, localhost

I have a local wamp, which used to work fine, then I needed iis, installed it, and set Apache to manual start/stop, I used iis, and then couple times switched between the two.
Now when I try to run Apache I get

```
(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 80.
```

I tried changing listen 80 to 0.0.0.0:80, and 127.0.0.1:80 but no luck.
The sites in iis are all stopped.

By running netstat -ao a first time it reported a PID 4 that was corresponding to SYSTEM, not knowing if I could end it, I rebooted, and now running netstat -ao I don't see any 80

I also tried listen 8080 and use httpd.exe from command, it did kinda worked, meaning the sites were missing styling, and perhaps something else, I did however installed a new script, and that site worked properly.

I then reverted to listen 80, and problem is there and netstat doesn't show any port 80 like stated above.

What else can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more research I found the culprit.
Although removed iis there still was the Web Deployment Agent Service running and using port 80.
Stopped it, and now Apache works fine as it used to.
To find out about it I used the following in command line:

```
netsh http show servicestate
```

it will show

```
Registered URLs:
HTTP://+:80/TheCulpritService
```

TheCulpritService is the service you would need to stop, to stop the service google it to find the steps for your system.